# Firebase Function doesn't respond after a few minutes of process and then timeouts

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, timeout, firebase-tools

I'm struggling with this error when calling my function in Firebase Functions. Problem is when the function process takes more than 2 minutes, it doesn't resolve nor finish and therefore idles until 9 minutes timeout showing the "540s timeout" error. This is happening with the firebase emulator.

Using:

```
firebase-tools: 8.16.2
firebase-functions: 3.3.0
```

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';

exports.setTestEnvironment = functions
.runWith({
    timeoutSeconds: 540, // max
    memory: '2GB', // max
})
.https.onCall(async (data: any, context: any) => {
    try {
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 120000)); // Sleep for 2 minutes, simulating processing.
        console.log('Done. Should return success and finish execution');
        return {
            success: true,
        };
    } catch (error) {
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('invalid-argument', error.message);
    }
});
```

The "Done" log appears after 2 minutes exactly, but function doesn't return the success nor finish execution. User who calls the function receives an error message even if function code processed correctly.

[image]

Am I doing something wrong here? I searched *almost* every github issue and stackoverflow question for this issue with no luck.

**UPDATE:**

Updating dependencies still throws same error.

firebase-tools: 10.1.5

firebase-functions: 3.19.0

Comment: Do you have the finished function to show us instead of this asynchronous simulation?

Comment: No, it's a long code. But just with the "sleep for 2 minutes" code the error occurs.

Comment: I created an issue in the github repo to see if anyone of the project can help
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/4378